# Foundation Grid System: What I'm doing wrong?

Tags: grid, zurb-foundation-5

I'm using the Foundation 5-Framework. I want to create a navigation with a panel under it. When im adding the panel, the navigationbar is always on top the panel.

This is my Code:

```
<div id="content">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="contain-to grid fixed">
                <nav class="top-bar" data-topbar role="navigation">
                    <ul class="title-area">
                        <li class="name">
                            <h1><a href="#">MySite</a></h1>
                        </li>
                        <li class="toggle-topbar menu-icon">
                            <a href="#"><span></span></a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                    <section class="top-bar-section">
                        <ul class="right">
                            <li class="active">
                                <a href="home.ctp">Index</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="#">Contact</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="#">About me</a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="has-dropdown">
                                <a href="#">Sign up</a>
                                <ul class="dropdown">
                                    <li>
                                        <a href="#">Log in</a>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </section>
                </nav>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="small-12 columns panel">
                <p>This is a panel.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please clarify the question. If you want "a navigation with a panel under it" that's already what you have: http://www.codeply.com/go/GBB5jr6Tyb

Answer (score 0):

You can either remove the class "fixed" from your third row (if you don't need a fixed positioned top bar),
or add margin-top to the second (panel) row (with the same height as the top-bar) if you wish to keep the top-bar fixed.

When an element is position fixed (like absolute and float) it is not actually on the page in the sense that static elements are not relative to it. so your panel was anchoring to the top of the page, because there was no block above it.
I am simplifying it a bit, but I hope that helps.